# Bootstrap Navbar Search Form Input has Error Class not being Applied

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm able to control the form the way I want to with javascript (at least form submission functionality wise), and a active working form is here on this code pen. However when the form is "invalid" i'm having trouble applying the bootstrap input class "has-error" to this form and turning the color around the input red. More can be found out about the "has-error" class here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation

https://codepen.io/MaineCannabisKid/pen/ZymzJO

Here is the Form code

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-nav search-form" method="get" action="search.php" name="searchForm" id="searchForm">
    <!-- hidden type input -->
    <input type="hidden" name="searchType" id="searchType" value="users" required>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="searchInput" name="searchInput" class="form-control" aria-label="Search the site" placeholder="Search Users">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="searchFormSubmit">Search</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="caret"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#" id="searchForm-users">Users</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="searchForm-another">Another Search</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and here's the javascript

```
console.log("Navbar.js Connected");

// Search Form Validate Function
function searchFormValidate() {
    // Check is Search Input value is null, if so return false (Validation didn't pass)
    return $('#searchInput').val() == "" ? false : true;
}

// When Search Users is clicked on
$('#searchForm-users').on('click', function() {
    $('#searchType').val('users');
    $('#searchInput').attr("placeholder", "Search Users");
});

// When Another Search is clicked on
$('#searchForm-another').on('click', function() {
    $('#searchType').val('another');
    $('#searchInput').attr("placeholder", "Search Something Else");
});

// When Search is clicked Submit Form
$("#searchFormSubmit").on('click', function() {
    if(searchFormValidate()) {
        document.searchForm.submit();
    } else {
        // Right here is where the form should apply the has-error class
        console.log("Validation Error");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fix your issue.

```
$("#searchInput").parent().addClass("has-error");
```

Note: the line around the input shows in `red` but due to your background colors, It won't visible to the eye.

```js
console.log("Navbar.js Connected");

// Search Form Validate Function
function searchFormValidate() {
  // Check is Search Input value is null, if so return false (Validation didn't pass)
  return $('#searchInput').val() == "" ? false : true;
}

// When Search Users is clicked on
$('#searchForm-users').on('click', function() {
  $('#searchType').val('users');
  $('#searchInput').attr("placeholder", "Search Users");
});

// When Another Search is clicked on
$('#searchForm-another').on('click', function() {
  $('#searchType').val('another');
  $('#searchInput').attr("placeholder", "Search Something Else");
});

// When Search is clicked Submit Form
$("#searchFormSubmit").on('click', function() {
  if (searchFormValidate()) {
    // form valid submit form
    document.searchForm.submit();
  } else {
    // form isn't valid, turn has-error on
    console.log("Validation Error");
    $("#searchInput").parent().addClass("has-error");
  }
});
```

```css
/* Navbar */

.navbar-default {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: transparent!important;
  border-color: transparent!important;
}


/* Navbar Search Form */

.search-form .btn-default {
  background: #ac3911;
  border-color: rgba(149, 48, 15, 1);
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: transparent!important;
}


/* Drop Down Button */

.search-form .btn-default.dropdown-toggle {
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(149, 48, 15, 1);
}


/* End Navbar Search*/
```

```html
<link href="https://bootswatch.com/united/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav-demo" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
      <a href="<?php echo Config::get('links/app_root'); ?>" class="navbar-brand hvr-grow">真 Makoto</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav-demo">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-nav search-form" method="get" action="#" name="searchForm" id="searchForm">
          <!-- hidden type input -->
          <input type="hidden" name="searchType" id="searchType" value="users" required>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" id="searchInput" name="searchInput" class="form-control" aria-label="Search the site" placeholder="Search Users">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="searchFormSubmit">Search</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
       </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#" id="searchForm-users">Users</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="searchForm-another">Another Search</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>


      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I'm also using "animate.css" by daneden/animate.css on github and that'll help too. Thanks for the help! CSS Changes complete as well.

Comment: I'm happy to year that. Please mark the post as the correct answer given and feel free to up vote as you like. :)